# Why is my LSTM giving the same prediction for similar words in different sentences?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, lstm

I have a corpus of sentences, where each sentence is 10 words long.
I want to build a neural net that will produce a binary classification for each word.

My approach has two phases. In the first phase I create character level embeddings and pass them in to an LSTM, to build a representation for each word.

In the second phase I pass the word representations for each sentence in to a second LSTM.

My model compiles and works but I am not sure it is doing what it is intended to do.

My main concern is that it gives the same prediction for similar words in different sentences. For instance for the following sentences: “cat sits on a mat”, “cat plays with a ball”, "cat is a cute animal" the word cat gets the same prediction, even though the sentences are different.

What am I doing wrong here? Your help and input is highly appreciated.

```py
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(
    input_dim=vocab_size,
    output_dim=char_embedding_size,
    input_length=input_length))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(24, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(50, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Reshape((1, 50)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(24, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Please see the model architecture image:
[image]

Comment: But what is the difference between the two `cat` words in those two sentences? What is the binary classification you're using?

Comment: I added another example in the post for clarification. The word cat is the same in all the sentences but all other parts of the sentence are different. LSTM predictions take in to account each word and all the other words in the sentence, the order of the words in the sentence and the content itself will effect the prediction resulting in the word "cat" having different predictions in different sentences. This is what I anticipated would happen but it is not happening, and that is the reason I think something is wrong with my LSTM.

Comment: Does this help https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_classification_rnn#stack_two_or_more_lstm_layers